# Python max list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I'm using the built-in max() function in Python like:

```
max(test_sentences, key=test_sentences.get)
```

What I'm using it for is to find a max value in a list (test_sentences) of a dictionary.
I'd like to get back that key, that has the greatest value on the [0] position in the list next to to the key.
An example (pls ignore u'):

```
{u'my name is tomi': [0, 1, 10, u'my', u'name', u'is', u'tomi'],
u'your name is tomi': [0, 1, 10, u'your', u'name', u'is', u'tomi'],
u'hello bello bye fine': [5, 42, 10, u'hello', u'bello', u'bye', u'fine'],
u'okkay tomi': [1, 1, 10, u'okkay', u'tomi'],
u'fine my name is tomi': [15, 1, 10, u'fine', u'my', u'name', u'is', u'tomi']}
```

In this case winner would be:

```
u'fine my name is tomi'
```

as the [0] element of the list is 15 and this is the greatest.

Actually the code I wrote just works:

```
max(test_sentences, key=test_sentences.get)
```

But I don't get it why... Can someone please help me and explain it... Just want to prevent mistakes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `max` on a dict, you are actually doing an operation on the keys of the dict, and ignoring the values. Same goes for other operations that treat your dictionary as an iterable, eg. `for k in dict:` etc. So if you just do `max(test_sentences)` you will just get the last key of your dictionary (in alphabetical order). If you want to use something else to sort by, you pass it in with `key`, where you provide a function to transform your value to the actual thing you're sorting by. `dict.get(k)` is the same as `dict[k]`, so in your code, your just saying for each key, get the corresponding value out of your dict, and use this to sort by. And the sort order on lists uses the first value first, which is what you're requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

`dict.get()` returns the value for the passed key. Sequences in Python are sorted naively. Putting the two together means that the key with the value of `[15, ...]` is returned from `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function takes an iterable as the first parameter, and when you iterate over a `dict` you will get all its keys iterated. so these are the same

```
max(test_sentences, key=test_sentences.get)
max(test_sentences.iterkeys(), key=test_sentences.get)
```

Then here is the `key` argument. It is a function that maps each item in the first argument to the return value for comparing. For any `key` in `test_sentences`, `test_sentences.get(key)` is of course the mapped value of the `key`. So you are getting all the list values compared.

Finally, when you compare two lists, in fact the comparison uses lexicographical ordering on each item in each list. You think you are using the first elements but actually not, though you could get the same result. Please read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) for more detail.

For what you need, I think it should be

```
max(test_sentences.iterkeys(), key=lambda key: test_sentences[key][0])
```